# stripping html tags in php with allowing an exception

Tags: php

For the past hour I've been trying to add an exception to strip tags, allowing only `<p></p>` to remain, but unfortunately I haven't been successful in making this work, I don't get any errors either, the trim is present because it's removing whitespace from the data, any feedback would be much appreciated, thank you very much

```
trim(strip_tags($html->find('div[id=data]',"<p></p>")));
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://3v4l.org/AVEA3).

Comment: Provide a sample of what `$html->find('div[id=data]'` returns.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please include more detail, including exactly what's wrong, the data you're using, and any other code that may have side effects.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance on asking a question.

Comment: @Qirel the returned data is a paragraph of text with html tags

Comment: @lake_house By the comment you posted below, it returned an array. So either you'll have to loop it, or use some `array_*` function. Depends a little on what you are using this data for, really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter is for `strip_tags`, not for `$html->find()`, and the value must be single tags without closing `'<p><span><pre>'`:

```
trim(strip_tags( $html->find('div[id=data]') ,"<p>"));
```

Comment: Actually, it shouldn't matter if you include the closing-tag as well, but you're absolutely correct on the parenthesis! Good eye!

Comment: @Igor I tried your recommendation above, I get the following error message, Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: @lake_house What is result of $html->find('div[id=data]')

Comment: @MrDuy trim(strip_tags($html->find('div[id=data]',0))); echo's two paragraphs of data, each paragraph has <p> at the beginning and </p> at the end, but they have been removed with strip tags, i'd like to have <p> and </p> present (not removed)

Comment: @lake_house If the output is an array , you can try `implode("",$html->find('div[id=data]'))`. I'm not sure what is the content of the array. You need to make it "plain" string to use it in strip_tags.

Comment: @lake_house Follow your explain I guess you are using dom. So it will be
`trim(strip_tags($html->find('div[id=data]', 0) , '<p>'));`
Because if you use: `$html->find('div[id=data]')` will return an array.

Answer (score 0):

Follow document on php.net

```
string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )
```

So if you want to keep `<p>` tag your code should be:

```
trim(strip_tags($html->find('div[id=data]'), '<p>'));
```

Comment: `p` is **incorrect**, you need to use the actual HTML, `<p>`! Don't believe me? [See for yourself](https://3v4l.org/uGf89).

Comment: @MrDuy I'm getting the following error message with the code above, Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: I think $html->find('div[id=data]') return array. So that is a reason you got that error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the common behaviour of php strip_tags() function that you can add the HTML tags that you want to allow.

If you have HTML content and suppose you would like to allow

tag then just add this as second parameter. For example:

```
strip_tags($html_text, '<p>');
```

For more you can check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)